# Serve multiple client request from server using bridge

Tags: vnc

My client basically make RDP kind of connection to server (see VNC server)

So, there are multiple client making connection to the server. To lower bandwidth, I want a bridge between server and clients. Basically this bridge will connect to server at a port and serve multiple client request.

I hope made my problem clear. Can anyone suggest what todo?
I want one connection from bridge to server and bridge should serve multiple client connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VNC there is a [VNC reflector](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vnc-reflector/) (bridge). You might be able to extend that to support RDP. I don't know of an existing RDP solution that is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh port forwarding to encrypt and compress traffic between your server and clients. For example, if you server runs on host `server` port 1234 and and bridge runs on host `bridge`, you set the tunnel up from host `bridge` like this:

```
[user@bridge ~]$ ssh -C -N -n -L *:1234:server:1234 server
```

So that when a client connects to `bridge:1234` the connection is forwarded to `server:1234` encrypting and compressing the traffic.

Comment: but it will be one to one connection. right? I want 1 connection from bridge to server and bridge should serve multiple client connection

Comment: Many to one. Once you established one tunnel you can connect as many clients as you wish to `bridge:1234`.

Comment: yes but it is still multiple connections from the RDP server point of view and it is still N times the amount of traffic even though all the connection are muxed through a single SSH connection. I think @honeybadger is trying to either reduce CPU load on the server or network bandwidth from the bridge to server which the SSH tunnel won't address. The RDP protocol probably won't compress all the well either.

Comment: @kanaka Exactly my point